# Js: last value set and get

Tags: javascript, arrays, get, set

> the fastest way to select the last element from an array is by `array[length - 1]`

However, as I get a larger nested array, I get something like this:

```js
let last_item = pathsry[
    pathsry.length - 1
    ][
        pathsry[
            pathsry.length - 1
        ].length - 1
    ]
```

It's not good man, therefore I overwrote following to get the last value.

```js
// get item at last index
Array.prototype.last = String.prototype.last = function(){
  return this[this.length - 1];
}
```

which allows me to get

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]];
console.log(arr.last().last().last());
// 'd'
```

However, if I try to set:

```js
Array.prototype.last = function(){
    return this[this.length - 1];
}

var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]];
arr.last().last().last() = 'dd';

// ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

is there a way I can write a function that takes a number as parameter which indicates the nested slices, and an optional parameter of set value, which:

```js
function arrayLast(arr, nes, val){
    // ...
}

var arra = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]];

console.log(arrayLast(arra, 3));
// d

arrayLast(arra, 3, 'dd');
console.log(arra);
// arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'dd']]]
```

appreciate for your help

Comment: I particularly don't want to use `flat` since it lowers performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help!

```
Array.prototype.last = function(val=null) {
  if (this.length === 0) {
    if (val) this[0] = val;
    else return null; 
  }
  
  temp = this;
  while(typeof temp[temp.length-1] === "object") {
    temp = temp[temp.length-1];
  }
  
  if (val) temp[temp.length-1] = val; //Setter  
  else return temp[temp.length-1]; //Getter
  
}

var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]];
console.log(arr.last()); // 'd'
    
arr.last("dd"); 
console.log(arr); // [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'dd' ] ] ]
```